# FabricObjectClosedException thrown from ReliableDictionary

Tags: azure-service-fabric

We are seeing occasional FabricObjectClosedExceptions thrown on calls on ReliableDictionary.AddOrUpdateAsync from within our services. Our api tests run over this code continuously but only fail a small percentage of the time so it does not seem to be an obvious issue with our own code but rather an issue with the underlying store.

The code being called is:

```
 using (var tx = StateManager.CreateTransaction())
 {
      // store the token
      await _tokens.AddOrUpdateAsync(
            tx,
            key,
            value,
            (s, entities) => value);
      await tx.CommitAsync();
 }
```

As mentioned, this code works most of the time but fails with a FabricObjectClosedException on occation. We've looked through logs but can't correlate this to anything we find.

Can somebody determine why the ReliableDictionary might be closed and whether or not we need some retry logic on this?

The exception is thrown on the AddOrUpdateAsync call has the following stacktrace (slightly formatted):

```
    Exception of type 'System.Fabric.FabricObjectClosedException' was thrown.
 at async Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Communication.Client.ServicePartitionClient`1.InvokeWithRetryAsync[](?)
 at async Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Remoting.Client.ServiceRemotingPartitionClient.InvokeAsync(?)
 at async Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Remoting.Builder.ProxyBase.InvokeAsync(?)
 at async Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Remoting.Builder.ProxyBase.ContinueWith(?)
 at async DataNamespace.Stores.BaseStore`1.StoreAsync[](?) 
 at async IdentityServer3.Core.Services.Default.DefaultTokenService.CreateSecurityTokenAsync(?)
 at async IdentityServer3.Core.ResponseHandling.TokenResponseGenerator.CreateAccessTokenAsync(?)
 at async IdentityServer3.Core.ResponseHandling.TokenResponseGenerator.ProcessTokenRequestAsync(?) 
 at async IdentityServer3.Core.ResponseHandling.TokenResponseGenerator.ProcessAsync(?) 
 at async IdentityServer3.Core.Endpoints.TokenEndpointController.ProcessAsync(?)
 at async IdentityServer3.Core.Endpoints.TokenEndpointController.Post(?) 
 at async System.Threading.Tasks.System.Web.Http908956.TaskHelpersExtensions.CastToObject[](?)
 at async System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionAsyncCore(?)
 at async System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.CallOnActionExecutedAsync(?)
 at async System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.CallOnActionExecutedAsync(?)
 at async System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore(?)
 at async System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.ExecuteAsync(?)
 at async System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore(?)
 at async System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.SendAsync(?)
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Fabric.FabricObjectClosedException: Exception of type 'System.Fabric.FabricObjectClosedException' was thrown.
 at System.Fabric.Store.TStore`5.ThrowIfFaulted(StoreReadWriteTransaction`4 rwtx)
 at System.Fabric.Store.TStore`5.<AddOrUpdateAsync>d__8a.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Data.Collections.DistributedDictionary`2.<AddOrUpdateAsync>d__1d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at DataNamespace.TokenPersistenceService.<StoreTokenAsync>d__11.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Remoting.Builder.MethodDispatcherBase.<ContinueWith>b__3(Task t)
 at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromTask`1.InnerInvoke()
 at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Remoting.Builder.MethodDispatcherBase.<Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Remoting.IMethodDispatcher.DispatchAsync>b__5(Task`1 t)
 at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
 at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Remoting.Runtime.ServiceRemotingDispatcher.<>c__DisplayClass5.<OnDispatch>b__4(Task`1 t)
 at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
 at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Remoting.Runtime.ServiceRemotingCancellationHelper.<DispatchRequest>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Communication.FabricTransport.Runtime.NativeServiceCommunicationMessageHandlerBroker.<RequestResponseAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
```

Comment: Can you correlate it to RunAsync being cancelled and/or CloseAsync being called? It might be due to cluster balancing then.

Comment: No, we were looking for something like this but could not find it in our logs.  Doesn't sound so pleasant though. Do you have experience on this? Is this something we should be guarding for within the service logic itself or should this be handled by caller retry logic (and is it already done by the service proxy)?

Comment: I've seen this during debugging, not in production (yet). The Service Proxy doesn't seem to retry on this error. Documentation says little on this. I think the caller should retry. The service can recycle. Do you get a meaningful ErrorCode on the exception? Do you save the ETW traces? Maybe up the loglevel.

Comment: If you are working with the new SDK 2.2, there was a bug in the Actor StateManager caused a FabricException to be thrown when adding and removing a variable within a single call context. See here: https://servicefabricsdkstorage.blob.core.windows.net/public-release-notes/Microsoft%20Azure%20Service%20Fabric%20Release%20Notes%20-%20SDK%202.2.207%20-%20Runtime%205.2.207.docx

Comment: @RotemVaron we are not using 2.2 and the code is not related to actors, so I don't think that we are seeing the mentioned bug.

Comment: @LoekD Seems strange that we essentially need to wrap all our client calls with retry logic for this exception, would expect the service proxy to handle this directly witin the framework rather than having us bloat ouor code. Are you using retries on all service calls or do you apply other patterns?

Comment: I am relying on the Proxy to do retries too. Maybe creating a custom ProxyFactory and Proxy implementation with additional logic would work. That way all extra retry logic would be confined there.

Comment: I had the same issue, and the cause was my app stepping on its self to access the same collection before another thread is done Commit. Adding `tx.CommitAsync().Wait();` to all places I Commit fixed the errors. (I do not know the performance implications of this.)

Comment: @Madushan we are already doing this via the `await tx.CommitAsync();` statement that is more resource friendly than the synchronous .Wait()

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the local cluster to use 5 nodes instead of 1.

I just ran into the same issue using v2.3.301. For whatever reason I was able to reproduce the problem at least 50% of the time while writing (AddOrUpdateAsync) to the IReliableDictionary.

After some research (not much out there) I found some reports that this is happening only on the local cluster. On a hunch I changed the 'mode' from 1 to 5 clusters and the problem seems to have gone away.

I haven't done much testing but have been unable to reproduce the problem using 5 clusters.

Note that once I see a FabricObjectClosedException no amount of retries makes it go away.